# pip destroying system files on fedora

Tags: python, fedora

I don't know what it is with python and fedora, but every time in past I tried to run pip(it's similar with npm/node), it was always destructive. And I always fell for that again and again not avoiding these commands. Today I found tool named `yq`, wrapper to jq. Docummentation asked for installation as easy as `pip install yq`. Missing root privileges. This should have warned me, that system files are about to be crippled again, but it didn't, I provided privileges.

From that point on, every start of bash complained, that I don't have privileges to run `/usr/bin/register-python-argcomplete`. At that point I already knew, that I'm in trouble again. I tried to uninstall `pip uninstall yq`, grant read privileges to all on this file, but nothing help. I'm stuck with message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/register-python-argcomplete", line 52, in <module>
    argcomplete.autocomplete(parser)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'autocomplete'
```

on every bash start. Please — how to get rid of this? I don't possess python knowledge neither I have any mercy with it. We can incinerate every misbehaving python library in process if it in the end fix my system.

Comment: What versions of everything are you using? Where is python installed, etc.

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help me, but please ask more specifically. I'm java devel, NO python experience. I don't know what info could be helpful to you and probably how to find it. Python is probably installed along with fedora 30

Comment: I installed `yq` in a Python virtual environment to see what other dependencies are installed. Other packages are `argcomplete`, `importlib-metadata`, `PyYAML`, `xmltodict`, and `zipp`.  You could reinstall these from the Fedora repo, if they were installed to begin with.  Of course the Fedora names will be different and these packages may be dependents of other packages as well.  Welcome to dependency hell.  I take no responsibility for further destroying your system, but if you have the Fedora package `pdc-client` installed, you could try reinstalling it for a start,

Comment: ... same for Fedora package `python-argcomplete`.  I.e., execute, at your own risk, `dnf reinstall python-argcomplete pdc-client`.

Comment: @rickhg12hs sure, I got it. At this point my system is compromised no guarantee can be made. Namely becuse of that I REALLY appreciate that you spent your time and tried to help me, I wouldn't be able to do it, as I lack knowledge in this area. I did `sudo dnf reinstall python3-argcomplete.noarch python3-pyyaml.x86_64` to begin with and this change alone seemed to fix the issue. THANK YOU VERY MUCH. This system will have to be reinstalled, as it's fedora 30 which will die relatively soon, but you removed the urgency to do it soon. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo pip install` or `sudo pip3 install` is still not safe!
While this Fedora change took steps to make sudo pip installing less dangerous, there are still corner cases where it might destroy parts of your system. Never ever ever ever use `pip` or `pip3` with sudo. Use `pip --user` or Python virtual environments instead.

According to the fedora project more info can be found on here [Changes/Making sudo pip safe](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/Making_sudo_pip_safe)

Comment: yes, I know. Again, now. As I said, I always fell for this trap, as I'm not python developer, and I read it in some freaking tool documentation on web thinking, that nothing can go wrong. So now, like britney said — upps, I did it again. Could you recommend actions how to fix it? I don't care about removal of X reinstalling it.